# Where to use the override keyword in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Which is an ideal file to use `override` identifier in c++ `.h` or `.cpp`?

### war.h

```
class TimeStone : public InfinityStone
{
private:
    bool capturedByThanos() override; #1
};
```

### war.cpp

```
bool TimeStone::capturedByThanos() override #2
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In the header is surely enough but how do you override a non virtual private method?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - How do you know it's non-virtual? Presumably `InfinityStone` defines it as virtual.

Comment: @StoryTeller just an assumption, class isn't `final`, inheritance is `public` and the overridden method is `private`. It might well be that it's on purpose but given the question I assumed it's not (not that it might not be, anyway)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti there is nothing inherently wrong with OPs code other than being incomplete. Instead of speculating how it could be wrong you could ask for the missing code ;)

Comment: @user463035818 lol, right about asking. Inherently wrong? Definitely not, possibly _uncommon_ (borderline with suspicious) maybe.

Comment: I would say that the code as is perfectly exemplifies the utility of `override`. You don't need the base class definition before your eyes. The compiler will tell you if you got it wrong thanks to override.

Comment: @user463035818 Well it doesn't even compile so yes there are a few things wrong

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  - StoryTeller is correct in assuming the inherited function would be virtual.   If it wasn't the sample as shown would have a diagnosable error (i.e. it would not compile).  That is one of the  intended effects of `overide`.    There would be no point in the question if the method was not virtual.     And it is certainly possible to override inherited private virtual functions.

Comment: @Peter not really. While it's technically possible to use `override` changing accessibility (and some compilers allow it) it's not always the case (and a very dubious use-case, BTW). You last sentence is unclear, you MAY (with some compilers) override a public/protected virtual/abstract base class method and make it private but you certainly cannot override private virtual functions (which they do not make sense, BTW)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - RE: *"and some compilers allow it"*. You mean ["standard conforming compilers"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.virt). And you can override private functions just fine. Overriding is not an access to the function, so access control is not issue.

Comment: @Adriano - you're making an incorrect assumption.   Private virtual functions are allowed by the standard, as is overriding an inherited private virtual function.    They may not make sense *to you* but there are design techniques and idioms that rely on exactly what you say doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StoryTeller that's about `virtual` where the standard is fortunately specific. AFAIK (and I can't find anything to prove it wrong) standard does not say anything about `override` specifier then, technically, a compiler may be a standard conforming compiler while requiring the overridden method to do not change accessibility.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - *"technically, a compiler may be a standard conforming compiler while requiring the overridden method to do not change accessibility"* That is a factually wrong statement, and it's disproved by the the example in the very section I linked to. The presence of an `override` identifier is completely orthogonal to the act of overriding a function. It does nothing but request an extra check. If the check passes, and `override` is removed prior to a subsequent rebuild, that function is still overridden.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - but neither question nor other comments mention changing visibility. Changing visibility is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @Peter I see I worded that comment very badly. I'm not arguing if private virtual functions are allowed or not. I'm arguing that, outside NVI, I see it as something dubious and limited to very few use-cases - and I'm not alone on this - causing more confusion than benefits. It fits _well_ in this example because derived class is jut returning a different constant value (which itself alone is dubious).

Comment: @el.pescado that's true, it's the _boring Me_ that can't refrain to comment when seeing a private overridden function which returns a constant value... :|

Comment: @StoryTeller You're actually right, technically `override` shouldn't restrict normal rules for overridden functions.

Answer (score 56):

You can't put an override specifier when defining the function outside the class's member specification. The language doesn't allow it, and a compiler will complain. So there's really only one option.

Beyond that, this option also makes more sense. When declaring the function you are expressing an intent to override it. So putting `override` *there* at the point of expressing your intent makes sense. That is what you are asking the compiler to check here, your intent to override. The declaration is also enough to verify that function is originally declared virtual and that you got the signature right.

Comment: Specifically, because the `override` applies to the method declaration, it can be checked in every translation unit that includes the class definition. If it were used on the non-`inline` out-of-class method definition, it could only be checked in the single TU that includes the definition.